# To make a special non-normal matrix diagonalizable

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagonalization

Suppose there is a non-normal block matrix like following:
\begin{equation}
P_{1}=
\left[\begin{array}{cc}
0 & I\\
A_{1} & A_{2}\\
\end{array}\right]
\end{equation}
in which $0,I$ are respectively zero and unit matrices, $A_{1},A_{2}$ are $n*n$ real matrix. And $P_{1}^{T}P_{1} \ne P_{1}P_{1}^{T}$, which means that $P_{1}$ is a non-normal matrices. Though $P_{1}$ cannot be orthogonal diagonalized, there may exist some non-singular(non-unitary) matrices to diagonalize it.There is a example [Can non-normal matrices with double eigenvalues never be diagonalized?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/634196/can-non-normal-matrices-with-double-eigenvalues-never-be-diagonalized).

Now I am wondering in what conditions can a non-normal matrix $P_{1}$ be diagonalized. To be more specific, what conditions should matrices $A_{1},A_{2}$ satisfy to make $P_1$ diagonalizable?

I have got some knowledges that if $P_1$ has $2n$ linearly independent eigenvectors, then $P_1$ is similar to a diagonal matrix. However it is not easy to calculate the eigenvectors and dimension of eigenvectors space, so i want to get some more verifiable conditions represented by $A_1,A_2$, Thank you very much!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please complete your last sentence.

Comment: @José Carlos Santos Thank you! I have made a supplement.